# reading text file with utf-8 encoding using java

Tags: java, netbeans, file-io, encoding

I have problem in reading text file with utf-8 encoding
I'm using java with netbeans 7.2.1 platform

I already configured the java project to handle UTF-8 
javaproject==>right click==>properties==>source==>UTF-8

but still get the unknown character output:
����� �������� ���� �

the code:

```
File fileDirs = new File("C:\\file.txt");

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fileDirs), "UTF-8"));

String str;

while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

any other ideas?

thanks

Comment: What is the encoding of `System.out`?  What's your system encoding?

Comment: Are you sure, the input file is UTF-8 encoded?

Comment: thank you all for your comments. I found the solution to the problem.the text file was with ANSI encoding with arabic character. so to solve : BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fileDirs), "windows-1256"));--thanks all

Answer (score 43):

Use

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;     
    public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args){

    try {
        File fileDir = new File("PATH_TO_FILE");

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
           new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fileDir), "UTF-8"));

        String str;

        while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(str);
        }

                in.close();
        } 
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) 
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

You need to put UTF-8 in quotes

Comment: Bad practice to put in.close before the catch. Should be in a finally block. Also can use multi catch format in Java 8

Answer (score 13):

You need to specify the encoding of the **InputStreamReader** using the **Charset** parameter.

```
Charset inputCharset = Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1");
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis, inputCharset));
```

This is work for me. i hope to help you.

Comment: You are the champ! Thanks, brother :)

Comment: Lg g3 = work with utf-8 but not ISO-8859-1, and my ASUS = works with ISO-8859-1 but not in utf-8 ...

Answer (score 10):

You are reading the file right but the problem seems to be with the default encoding of `System.out`. Try this to print the `UTF-8` string-

```
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8");
out.println(str);
```

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same problem every time it finds a special character marks it as ��. to solve this, I tried using the encoding: ISO-8859-1

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("txtPath"),"ISO-8859-1"));

while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

}
```

I hope this can help anyone who sees this post.

Comment: There's no *ISO-8859-1* encoding set in the code. The encoding is the default

Answer (score 4):

Ok, I am definitively late to the party but if you are still looking for an optimal solution I would use the following ( for Java 8 )

```
    Charset inputCharset = Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1");
    Path pathToFile = ....
    try (BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader( pathToFile, inputCharset )) {
        ...
     }
```