# Encoding problems in database

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, encoding

I have a postgres 9.2 database, which encoding is UTF-8.
I have an application(written in java) to update this database, reading .sql files and executing them in the database.
But i found a problem:
In one of those .sql files, i have the following instruction:

```
insert into usuario(nome)
values('Usuário Padrão');
```

After executing this, when i go to the table data, what was inserted was this: `"UsuÃ¡rio PadrÃ£o"`

If i execute this command directly from pgAdmin, it creates correctly.
So i don't know if it's a problem in database, or in the program that executes the scripts.

---EDIT---

Here is how i get a JDBC connection:

```
public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException{
    Connection connection;
    String url="jdbc:postgresql://"+servidor+":"+porta+"/"+nomeBanco;
    Properties props = new Properties();  
    props.put("user", usuario);  
    props.put("password", senha);
    connection=DriverManager.getConnection(url,props);
    connection.setAutoCommit(false);
    return connection;
}
```

And here is the code i use to read the file, but this looks correct, because if i print the String read from the file, it shows the correct String.

```
public static String lerArquivo(File arquivo){
    StringBuilder conteudo=new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(arquivo));
        String linha;
        while((linha=br.readLine())!=null){
            conteudo.append(linha).append("\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        FrameErroBasico f=new FrameErroBasico(null, true);
        f.setText("Erro ao ler arquivo.",e);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }finally{
        try{br.close();}catch(Exception e){}
    }
    return conteudo.toString();
}
```

Comment: how would we know?  should we guess at what your java code looks like?  staring into my crystal ball, i'm going to wager that your java code does not open the sql script files using an explicit character encoding.

Comment: Check what client encoding your app sets, when it creates a DB session.

Comment: sorry i forgot about that crystal bal thing... i updated my question with the code i use to get the Connection.

Comment: show the code from where you read the sql script

Comment: Run `SHOW client_encoding` in the same session to get definitive info about your actual setting.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter PgJDBC unconditionally uses `utf-8` as client-encoding and works with Java's Unicode strings, so the problem must be with how they read the data in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is most likely the problematic line:

```
    br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(arquivo), "UTF-8"));
```

(looks like my crystal ball is still working well!)

Comment: Yeah that was the problem!
Though there was a scratch in the crystal ball. If anyone is having the same issue, the right way to solve it is like this: br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(arquivo),"UTF-8")); Thank you!

Comment: @MateusViccari - ooops, yeah, swapped my streams, should have written it a little more carefully.  the issue wasn't the ball, just my fat fingers.

Answer (score 1):

To be sure I'd need to see the code that reads the SQL file in, but (as pointed out by jtahlborn) I'd say you're reading the file with an encoding other than the encoding it really has.

PgJDBC uses Unicode on the Java side and takes care of client/server encoding differences by always communicating with the server in utf-8, letting the server do any required encoding conversions. So unless you set `client_encoding` via your PgJDBC connection - something PgJDBC tries to detect and warn you about - the problem won't be on the PostgreSQL/PgJDBC side, it'll be with misreading the file.

Specifically, it looks like the file is utf-8 encoded, but you are reading it in as if it was latin-1 (ISO-8859-1) encoded. Witness this simple demo in Python to replicate the results you are getting by converting a native Unicode string to utf-8 then decoding it as if it was latin-1:

```
>>> print u'Usuário Padrão'.encode("utf-8").decode("latin-1");
UsuÃ¡rio PadrÃ£o
```

Your application most likely reads the file into a `String` in a manner that performs inappropriate text encoding conversions from the file encoding to the unicode text that Java works with internally. There is no reliable way to "auto-detect" the encoding of a file, so you must *specify* the text encoding of the input when reading a file. [Java typically defaults to the system encoding, but that can be overridden](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1006276/398670). If you know the encoding of the file, you should [explicitly pass it when opening the file for reading](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14918188/398670)

You haven't shown the code that reads the file so it's hard to be more specific, but this is really a Java side issue not PostgreSQL-side. If you `System.out.println` your SQL file from Java you'll see that it already mangled in your Java string before you send it to the database server.

Comment: very verbose description which is basically the same as my first comment.  unfortunately, the OP has not shown the relevant code.

Comment: @jtahlborn Explaining things to people who don't understand them is a significant part of what this site is about, no?

Comment: indeed.  my comment wasn't necessarily a criticism, however, it's all just a shot in the dark without the relevant code from the OP.

Comment: i will put the code i use to read the file. but i've already tried to do a System.out.println() on the String i execute via preparedStatement. And it shows in the console the correct String, without the strange carracters.

Comment: @MateusViccari That would actually make sense if your console is in the same encoding. What if you print the *bytes* of the string? Print the contents of the byte array returned by `thestring.getBytes("utf-8")` and post it here.

Answer (score 0):

As jtahlborn said, the right way to read the file is like this:

```
br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(arquivo),"UTF-8"));
```

That was my problem, doing like this, it works like a charm.